# How to solve this first order ODE (i'm getting the wrong answer)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy-y^2}{x^2}$ using the substituion $y=x v$ where $v$ is a function of $x$.

My method:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dv}{dx}=v-v^2$ after making the substitution $y=xv$

Therefore,

$\int \frac{dv}{v-v^2}=\int \frac{dx}{x}$

$\int \frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{1-v}dv=\int \frac{dx}{x}$ after applying partial fractions

$ln(v)-ln(1-v)=ln(x)+C$

Replacing $v$ with $v=y/x$, I get:

$ln(y)-ln(x-y)=ln(x)+C$

But the answer says:

$x/y = ln(x)+C$

Have I made a mistake somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: You have to apply the chain rule, so $\frac{d(xv)}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$.

Comment: @Miguel Ohh, I understand my mistake now. Thanks! It seems I treated v as a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Miguel for pointing out my mistake in the comments above. I didn't apply the chain rule to $\frac{dy}{dx}$, which should lead to $$v+x \frac{dv}{dx}$$